# Can i configure a PCCC Node with a function node before it?

Tags: node.js, node-red, ethernet, plc

is there any way to use a function node to configure the variable address of a PCCC node?, i have this big structure of data, each data has its own specific key, soy if i can find a way to iterate the configuration of the PCCC node it will a lot faster than do it one by one, consider there are a litle bit more than thousand keys

Comment: If asking about a specific node please include a link to the node on flows.nodered.org in the question so we can find it without guessing

Comment: this is the pccc node link https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-pccc

Answer (score 1):

Having looked at the source code it appears you can pass in a value in `msg.variable` which appears to correspond to the Addressing mentioned in the README.md https://github.com/st-one-io/node-red-contrib-pccc/blob/master/README.md#addressing

> **Addressing**
>
> The addresses follow the same syntax of what would be used on RSLogix,
> so for example B3:0/0 addresses the bit 0 of byte 0 in the file B3,
> and F8:1 points to the float 1 at the file F8.

You will need to leave that field empty in the pccc-out node's configuration for it to be used.